# react native runs component code while it's not rendered

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have LoginPage and UserPage.

when I start the app with LoginPage, codes on UserPage runs too.

I need to fetch user data when entered in UserPage.

so I'm dispatching fetchUserData action on componentWillMount func on UserPage.

```js
componentWillMount(){
  let props = this.props;
  props.fetchUserData(props.navigation.state.params.userId);
}
```

as we all know, we can never have "params.userId" in navigation state before logging in.

but when I start app, codes on UserPage runs without any userId.

I got undefined error for this.

so I did something like this in UserPage

```js
componentWillMount(){
  let props = this.props;
  if(props.navigation.state.params)
    props.fetchUserData(props.navigation.state.params.userId);
}
```

but I don't understand why should I do it like this.

normally, if you don't navigate to the page,

the code on the page should not run.

I heard that react native check coded before starting an app,

is this really happening because of that?

---

### Question Updated

Ok I'll add more details.
first, this is my  navigator configuration

```js
//this is my auth navigator which contains login and sign up page
export default AuthNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Login: {screen: LoginPage},
  SignUp: {screen: ModalSignUp}
},{mode: "modal"});


//this is tab navigator configuration which will be shown after log in
const generalStacks = {
  UserPage: {screen: UserPage}
};

const FeedStacks = StackNavigator({
  FeedPage:{screen:FeedPage}, ...generalStacks
});

const MyPageStacks = StackNavigator({
  ...generalStacks
});

const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  FeedTab : {
    screen: FeedStacks
  },
  MyPageTab : {
    screen: MyPageStacks,
    }
  }
});

const modals = {
  ModalUserProfile: { screen: ModalManageUserProfile },
};

export default RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Tabs: {screen: Tabs},
  ...modals
},{mode: "modal"});



// and I wrap AuthNavigator, RootNavigator in AppNavigator
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  AuthNavigator: {screen: AuthNavigator},
  RootNavigator: {screen: RootNavigator}
});
```

actually, I got this problem after login.

when I move in to FeedTab in RootNavigator.

FeedStacks contains FeedPage and UserPage.

so the problem is the codes on UserPage runs when I enter FeedPage.

and this is how I render my user page

```js
class UserPage extends Component{
  componentWillMount(){
    let props = this.props;

    if(props.navigation.state.params){
      props.fetchUserBooks(props.navigation.state.params.id);
    }
  }

  render(){
    let props = this.props;
    let userId, userPage;

    if(props.navigation.state.params && props.userPages[props.navigation.state.params.id]){
      userId = props.navigation.state.params.id;
      userPage = props.userPages[userId];

      return (
        <View>
          <UserData user={userPage.user}/>
        </View>
      )
    }else{
      return <View><Text>isFetching</Text></View>;
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToUserPageProps = (state) => {
  return {
    userPages : state.userPages
  }
};

const mapDispatchToUserPageProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchUserBooks: (userId) => {dispatch(fetchUserData(userId));}
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToUserPageProps, mapDispatchToUserPageProps)(UserPage);
```

Comment: Can you share some code about how you render the UserPage?

Comment: Can you share your navigator's configuration?

Comment: I updated my navigator configuration & how I render my UserPage @zarcode

Comment: updated question! @john_ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabNavigator by default loads all its child components at the same time.

Currently, there is an option `lazy` that tells whether to render every component when needed or to render every component beforehand. When setting `lazy` to true you can see the components rendering while swiping. It's in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#TabNavigatorConfig).

I would suggest you try:

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator(
    {
      FeedTab : {
        screen: FeedStacks
      },
      MyPageTab : {
        screen: MyPageStacks,
        }
      }
    },
    {
        lazy: true
    }
);
```

Comment: @SimonJo you can accept the answer if it helped you. Even "upvote" if you want :)